# Link to user directory displayed with wrong name in start menu

Tags: windows-vista, user-accounts, start-menu

In the start menu the link to my user directory is displayed with a wrong name e.g. foo

When I click on the link in the start menu the explorer opens my correct user directory but the addressbar still names it foo.

However, when I open a cmd from that directory the location is correctly shown as C:\Users\myUserName. Furthermore there is no C:\Users\foo directory.

How can I fix this (i.e. ths link in the startmenu should be named myUserName)?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searched google and found [this interesting thread at techsupportforum](http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f217/solved-accidentally-changed-name-of-start-menu-user-folder-600167.html).

They propose a solution which look like this:

- `regedit` on this branch `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CLSID\{59031A47-3F72-44A7-89C5-5595FE6B30EE}`
- delete the `(Default)` value, which it resets to `(value not set)` state
- then you will need to restart the `explorer.exe` process or just simply log out and in

[image]